Why am I getting runtime error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0'" after installing a NuGet package?
I recently installed a NuGet package into one of the projects in my solution. There were no issues during installation. There are no issues with building my code, rebuilding my code, or starting up the code for debugging in Visual Studio. However, while debugging, whenever my code reaches a point where it would call .Where() on an IQueryable, I get an error:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Notably, this ONLY happens if I make use of the new NuGet package in my code - for example, by calling a constructor or function from it. If I don't use it at all, or if I just have "using" statements pointing to it but don't do anything with them, I do not get this error.
Nothing in my solution references System.Runtime.Loader at all. In fact, as far as I can tell, nothing in the NuGet package references System.Runtime.Loader either. Also, nothing that references any part of "System.Runtime" references version 4.0.0.0. So I have no idea why the code is looking for this file, or how I can fix this situation. (I also have no idea why this error only occurs when trying to execute .Where() on an IQueryable. The exact same uses of .Where() work fine as long as the new package contents are not being referenced anywhere in my code.)
EDITED TO ADD: I am seeing people saying things in other threads like "System.Runtime.Loader is not supported for .Net Framework". My project is in .NET Framework. I have actually opened the other project from which the NuGet package was published, and it is also in .NET Framework. So I have absolutely no idea why, at runtime, something is looking for System.Runtime.Loader, even though it isn't referenced in code anywhere and is supposedly not supported in either project. As far as I know, both projects run just fine on their own, so I also cannot see how it's possible that either of them is referencing System.Runtime.Loader indirectly through some other package.

This error is a precursor from very annoying family of warnings during compilation. Inspect your compilation log for warnings about "reference". Even better, make them as errors. Some  nested packages uses this library twice with different versions. This is common error in current time because half of useful packages still reside in .net4.* and supporter probably dead.

Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, there were already a ton of reference warnings that we were already getting on the main branch. In the branch where I installed this NuGet package, the only new warning was one about System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe. The issue was between versions 4.0.4 and 5.0.0. What's crazy is main branch already has a warning about 4.0.4 versus 6.0.0 but it still works. So I changed all references from 5.0.0 to 6.0.0... and it's still broken.

Until you fix those - you are in trouble I guess. I doubt you/team want to support code where someone engraved some library version in stone, because if major version differ usually it means they are not compatible on some methods. Some would work (this is why 4.0.4 worked). Some not (your case). There is no way around    . I negated this family of errors using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management . Its greatly enhanced nuget management.

Forgot to mention, migration to CPM is usually a long process (week maybe), but then you will never encounter them again. Look on internet, people already widely use it and its really helping. Especially if you have your own nuget repo in company/team. You just mark your common libs as single version everywhere and whe you update those common libs - you update single line in main solution.

Please see my edit. Do you think it's possible that NuGet somehow caused this issue? Or Visual Studio? I don't see how publishing something that couldn't possibly use System.Runtime.Loader, then installing the published package into something else that couldn't possibly use System.Runtime.Loader, somehow makes Visual Studio go looking for System.Runtime.Loader... and only when .Where() is hit.
